# How to set grequests timeout

Tags: python, grequests

How would I accomplish the following:

```
rs = (self.exporter.grequester(url) for url in url_chunk)
res_items = grequests.map(rs, timeout=10s) # this is the item that times out
```

Comment: in requests the call is like requests.get(URL, timeout=(3,10))  so try taking out the 's' in 10s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
reqs = grequests.map(grequests.get(link, headers=header,  timeout=1) for link in links)
```

[source](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)